# Passing react select value in react js to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I used react-value to add dropdown selections that will appear upon click oncall function, and pass in some static values that I hardcoded as seen in the following codes:

```
import React, {useMemo, useState} from "react"
import Select from 'react-select'
import { db } from '../firebase/config'
import { collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function JobApplication() {

const timeline = [
        { value: 'one-week', label: 'In one week'},
        { value: 'two-weeks', label: 'In two weeks'},
        { value: 'one-month', label: 'Within a month'},
        { value: 'more', label: 'More than a month'},
    ]
```

The values that I hardcoded inside the const timeline is then passed into the following codes:

```
<div className="flex flex-col mt-12 items-start">
                <label className="mb-3 text-sm leading-none text-gray-800">When can you start?</label>
                <Select required key={timeline} options={timeline} onChange={changeHandler} />
        </div>
```

So I wrapped the Select call inside form, and passed in the function of onSubmit={handleSubmit} which I created through the following code:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        navigate('/home')
```

Is there any method to pass in the hardcoded selected values from the timeline into Firebase once user made their selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use UseState hook to store selectedTimeline then make a changeHandler then update the handleSubmit

```
const [selectedTimeline, setSelectedTimeline] = useState(null);


const changeHandler = (selectedOption) => {
  setSelectedTimeline(selectedOption.value);
};

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "jobApplications"), {
    timeline: selectedTimeline,
    // u can  other form data 
  });

  navigate('/home');
};
```